# class creates own objekts

Tags: python, class, object

Is it possible for a class to create a number of objects n if I assign n a value? Assuming I have 100 cars that are identical and I want to create an object for each car, I could call a class that creates 100 objects (cars). I couldn't find anything about it on the internet and I don't know what exactly to look for. thanks for the replies

Comment: You should start by showing us a "use case". This could clarify the question and your needs.

Comment: does that solve it?

class_objects = [MyClass() for i in range(100)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of a static factory method:

```
class Car:
  def __init__(self, ...):
    ...
  
  @classmethod
  def make_car_array(cls, n=100):
    return [Car() for i in range(n)]
```

and then call

```
array_of_cars = Car.make_car_array()
```

Comment: You probably meant `@staticmethod` ...

Comment: @Demi-Lune why?

Comment: Because the code doesn't work :-)  `TypeError: 'type' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.   @classmethod passes the class as 1st argument `def f(cls, *other_args)`. Cf. [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod)

Comment: @Demi-Lune You're right, I missed that, my bad. First argument added.